# Printing functions in cpp

Tags: c++, function

Why is it that any time i print a function in cpp, it prints 1. i.e

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f1(){
   cout<<"called function f";
}
int f2(){
   cout<<"called f2";
   return 1;
}
int main(){
   cout << f2 <<endl; // prints 1
   cout << f1 <<endl; // still prints 1
}
```

Im just wondering why it prints 1.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `f` is not defined. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You want to call the functions, not to output their function pointers: `cout << f2() <<endl;`, same for the other one. VTC as typo.

Comment: @EkureEdem Your edit even prooves my concern more.

Comment: @pei no dont want to call it

Comment: What do you expect to be printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is judging if the functions (converted to pointers to functions) are not null, returning `true`, and printing `true` as 1. This can be confirmed by adding `cout << std::boolalpha;` and seeing the the output is changed to `true`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f1(){
   cout<<"called function f";
}
int f2(){
   cout<<"called f2";
   return 1;
}
int main(){
   cout << std::boolalpha;
   cout << f2 <<endl; // prints true
   cout << f1 <<endl; // also prints true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why the down vote